# Dynamically  recursive in mips

Tags: mips

I want to make a dynamically linked list

Comment: Please make your question more complete and show what you have already tried so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it in C and take a peek at what the C compiler generates. This might point you in the right direction.. aka gcc -S -c myexample.c

However if it is homework, it might be the wrong thing for you todo.